# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined and code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({
  path: path.resolve(path.__dirname, `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`),
});

export default config = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  HOST: process.env.HOST || "localhost",
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 3001,
};
```

When i try to make config.js file to work multiple .env files but i get this error.os : windows 10

Answer (score 1):

i solved with that:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({
  path: path.resolve(path.dirname("/"), `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`),
});
const config = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  HOST: process.env.HOST || "localhost",
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 3001,
};


export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` is not located in the `path` module so `path.__dirname` is undefined.

You should use `__dirname`.

See here :
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname#:~:text=__dirname%20is%20an%20environment,js%20project](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname#:%7E:text=__dirname%20is%20an%20environment,js%20project).

Comment: i did that too but this time i get this error "ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined"

Comment: See here : https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#no-__filename-or-__dirname

Comment: __dirname doesn't work if you're using  ES6 modules